# Getting error as "Incorrect type.Expected "null"." in settings.json on VS Code for my terminal.integrated.automationProfile setting

Tags: visual-studio-code, null

I wrote the following in my VS Code settings.json:

```json
"terminal.integrated.automationProfile.osx": {}
```

which is giving me this error:

```
Incorrect type. Expected "null".
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: That error is pointing to the property `terminal.integrated.automationProfile.osx` (`"startLineNumber": 135`, `"endLineNumber": 137`), not the one you inserted. The syntax is wrong; remove the trailing comma and that should fix it.

Comment: @wjandrea that's weird though. when functioning properly, VS Code accepts trailing commas for settings.json.

Comment: @starball Oh right, VSC config files use JSONC. Then I guess the error is the empty object. There's no reason for it to be there anyway, so I guess just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

It's invalid to set `terminal.integrated.automationProfile` to an empty object. If you don't want to set anything for that setting, you're supposed to set it to `null`. If you do want there to be something there, you need to at least set the `path` property of the object value.